# Want to detect incorrect user name and or password when running IBM Doors in batch mode

Tags: python, error-handling, subprocess, ibm-doors

I'm using a Python sub-process to start IBM Doors in batch mode with a DXL script and an outside variable. When I run the script usually it runs fine, but sometimes the return value is empty.
Other problem occurs when I purposely give incorrect user credentials. Doors opens a window which I'd like to close by the code and write out the error but, the error appears only after closing the window by hand.
I had used a temporary directory for exports which I checked from Python and when an update happened I handled it, but reading from std out seemed to be a better solution.

---

- Can **-caching (-k)** increase reliability (in case of the
  empty returns)?
- Is it possible to catch **-E- DOORS: Invalid username or password** massage and similar error massages during the run before closing the window and  close the batch run from code in case of an error?

.py

```
import subprocess
import os

if __name__ == '__main__':
  script_name = 'demo_dummy_script.dxl'
  filename = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath('__file__')), script_name)

  var = "apple"
  proc = subprocess.Popen(r'"C:\Program Files\IBM\Rational\DOORS\bin\doors.exe"'
                           r' -dxl "string myVar = \"'
                           + var +
                           r'\"" -b '
                           + filename +
                           r' -osuser',
                           stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                          stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
  stdout = proc.communicate()
  encoding = 'utf-8'
  print(stdout[0].decode(encoding).split())
```

.dxl

```
cout << myVar
```

Using Doors 9.6, Python 3.6, Windows10

Comment: Welcome at SO! And good luck with that issue!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest adding the '-W' switch to your command-line statement. This can be found under 'nowait' [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSYQBZ_9.6.1/com.ibm.doors.configuring.doc/topics/c_clientcommandswitches.html). Make sure you capitalize the W!

Caching is trickier- it depends what you are trying to do. I would suggest trying it with and without and seeing which behavior you prefer. I don't use it, but my applications running in batch mode tend to be uni-directional (the user is looking at DOORS data but not writing to DOORS)

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
I tried the -W but sadly doesn't seem to solve the problem. The run still ends up in a black empty Doors window.

Comment: It seems like, changing the "-osuser" to "-u username -P passw" solved the problem and the error message returns to the standard output. Now, the -W is working as well.